# Gradle test: show standard streams only with specific tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, gradle

While testing with Gradle, I'd like to show standard streams on the console *only* when I run a specific subset of tests with the `--tests` option.

Let me elaborate. On `build.gradle` I have

```
test {
    testLogging {
        //showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Usually, when I run my whole test suite, I don't like to have console output from the tests. But when I'm working on a specific test, it's very useful to have console output, so I go ahead and uncomment that line before executing that test with `gradle test --tests *name`.

I'd like to know if there's an automated way to do that.

**EDIT:** Let my clarify. I'd like to have console output when I run `gradle test --tests *name`, but not when I run `gradle test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get console output on some runs for all tests, you could supply an additional parameter (-Poutput) on command-line:

`gradle test --tests *name -Poutput`

```
test {
    onOutput { descriptor, event ->
        if (project.hasProperty('output')) {
            logger.lifecycle(event.message)
        }
    }
}
```

To get console output on a specific test only:

```
test {
    onOutput { descriptor, event ->
        if (descriptor.name=='YOUR_TEST_METHOD_NAME' &&
                descriptor.className=='YOUR_PACKAGE_QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME') {
            logger.lifecycle(event.message)
        }
    }
}
```

See [TestDescriptor](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestDescriptor.html) and [Test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html)

Comment: not working with either gradle run or gradle run --tests *name http://codepad.org/bdzJya6I

Comment: gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-09-14 07:26:16 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     c41505168da69fb0650f4e31c9e01b50ffc97893

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-65-generic amd64

Comment: Don't know how to do it without supplying an additional parameter.  Apparently, the command line arguments are difficult to access reliably.  See my last edit.

Comment: `-Poutput` does nothing on 6.8.1 (though I have a bunch of other options).

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I'm using an alternative approach using by reading the command line flag `--info`

```
test {
    if (project.gradle.startParameter.logLevel == LogLevel.INFO) {
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        testLogging.exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
}
```

So when running `gradle test --info`, I'll see more gradle details includint test output. With this setup, I see other gradle informations like dependencies versions, which can be useful.

However I think the above answer allows more control on the output indeed, e.g. :

```
onOutput { descriptor, event ->
    if (project.hasProperty('output')) {
        def withoutLastLineFeed = event.message.substring(0, event.message.length() - 1)
        logger.lifecycle("{} ===> {}", 
                         event.destination, 
                         withoutLastLineFeed)
    }
}
```